# Click on FCM Notification not opening apps when sent by API Call

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem regarding the click action of the FCM Push notification when an app is on background.
When I try to send a notification from the firebase console, the information is received and if I click the notification, the apps open.
But when I try to send a notification via Postman. the notification is also received but when I click it, the app doesn't open.

Payload:

```
{
    "to": "--mytoken--",
    "notification": {
        "click_action": "home",
        "title": "Title Notification",
        "body": "Body Notification"
    },
    "data": {
        "body": "Body of Your Notification in Data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
        "type": "edit_profile",
        "id_reference": "0",
        "badger": "1",
        "inbox_subject": "",
        "news_title": "YYY",
        "url": "https://yamie2.co.id/news/webview/3",
        "icon": "https://yamie.co.id/images/icon.png"
    }
}
```

I create an android app with ReactJS and Capacitor

Comment: In the Postman case, you are responsible for creating the notification.  By default, a notification will display the app when it is clicked on.  But you can override this by calling `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` when you create the notification.  Are you calling `setContentIntent`?  Please update your question to include how you are creating the notification.

Comment: @EdmundJohnson, I am not creating the notification manually, all notifications are created by FCM SDK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the activity that you want to open has an intent filter with `home` set to that action.

See also:

- [click_action of Notification Message of Firebase push notifications are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42524716/20447561)
- [FCM Notification click_action not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383425/20447561)